# How to Type check for enum instance base class?

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum type which derives from byte. 
In my common library, at some point there is a cast of an enum parameter to int.
The problem is when my byte derived enum gets to that method in the common library, the cast to int fails and raises an exception.

Is there a way to type check an enum's base class so I can do the Int cast only for int based enums?

Here are two sample enums:

```
enum DaysByte : byte { Sat = 1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri };
enum DaysInt  : int  { Sat = 1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri };
```

Comment: Can you please post some sample code?

Comment: Take a look at the Enum.GetUnderlyingType method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getunderlyingtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Enum.GetUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getunderlyingtype(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(YourEnum)) == typeof(int)

// or via enum value
Enum.GetUnderlyingType(yourEnumValue.GetType()) == typeof(int)
```

Comment: What if he only has the value?

Comment: @TimSchmelter added that too. is that what you mean?